# Correctly representing nested/sub components in EA 16

Tags: components, uml, instance, enterprise-architect

Assume I have the following structure:

[image]

Currently it is best practice in my company to represent sub-components in the following way.

[image: Invalid]

This is, however, not valid as it is impossible to have the same sub-component twice (imagine having a car with 4 tires) and it is lacking the horizontal line on the parent component, which indicates the compartment.

Now, in EA15 I would be able to insert the sub-component as an instance. The image below shows a result, which is in line with the example provided by the [UML 2.5.1 specification](https://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5.1/PDF) on page 214 and therefore **desired**.

[image: Looks valid]

Unfortunately, inserting the sub-component as an instance in EA16 yields:

[image: Not in line with UML 2.5.1?]

In the UML specification the underline is reserved for instances. Hence, EA16 now represents the instance correctly (in contrast to EA15). However, the UML specification explicitly mentions for the example on page 214 that it shows a "Component that contains other Components" and not a component that contains instances of other components.

[image: Example from UML 2.5.1 specification]

So, how do I produce the correct output in EA16?

*Note: I also considered to insert the sub-component as a property (part is not available). One of the major downsides is that the icon for the component is missing. This might be counter-intutitive to most of my colleagues.*

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a bug in EA, and nothing you can influence yourself.

Comment: Actually the picture at the bottom shows instances as well. The `:` identifies the classifier.

Comment: Seel p. 126 od UML 2.5: _It is not necessary to show an underlined name where..._

Comment: @qwerty_so: I looked it up in UML 2.5.1 on p. 128 and this does not seems to be applicable for components as it reads in full: *An InstanceSpecification **whose classifier is an Association** represents a link and is shown using the same notation as for
an Association, but the solid path or paths connect InstanceSpecifications rather than Classifiers. It is not necessary to show an underlined name where it is clear from its connection to instance specifications that it represents a link and not an Association...*

Comment: The appropriate text has moved further down to p. 170. However, you're probably right this is not what you're looking for. But in the example they use `Part`s (as can be read _Ports to handling parts_). So that's probably what you want to use in EA.

Comment: @qwerty_so: As mentioned in my post, part is not offered by EA. How do you feel about using instances instead? Do you see downsides?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As usual EA has it's own way of naming things. If you start with this

[image]

then you can drag the `Sub Component` from the browser over `Main Component`. Now from the dialog that pops up

[image]

choose *Property* and *OK*.

EA will plaster that "somewhere"

[image]

Now you have to resize `Main Component` and then move `Sub Component` so it will dock inside. And voila (or whatever the Aussies say):

[image]

there is your `Part`!

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. Is there a way to show the component icon in the part in EA? (I guess that otherwise people might not understand )

Comment: No, unless you stereotype it via a MDG and create an according shape script.